# How can I comment comma-separated array values?

Tags: wp-query, query-posts, array

I realise this is perhaps more of a php question rather than WP-specific, but figure/hope it's relevant.

I annotate my code probably more than is needed (because I know relatively little about this, and it helps me to better understand).

I'm wondering how best to deal with these two instances...

In:

```
$query->set( 'post__not_in', array(
41,     // page title
43,     // /page title
) );
```

BBEdit syntax highlight is ok, and the code works.

Whereas in:

```
wp_list_pages( array(
'exclude'               => '
41, // page title
43, // page title
',
) );
```

BBEdit syntax highlight is incorrect, but the code works.

Is it ok (reliable) to include such comments - and is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No, it's definitely not okay to comment your code this way.** It changes the string, and even though WordPress might strip the incorrect characters and yield the correct pages (it wouldn't if your "comments" contained comma's or numbers), it is incredibly unstable. Instead, if you do want to comment them, I would suggest storing them as an array, commenting that in the way you described, and [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)-ing it with a comma:

```
$exclude_ids = array(
    41, // First page title
    43, // Second page title
);

wp_list_pages( array(
    'exclude' => implode( ',', $exclude_ids ),
) );
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Appreciated. Having had a quick look at that 'implode' link I shall study it more so I can better understand.

Comment: Quick follow-up, sorry for my confusion. Having modified my use of wp_list_pages accordingly, I'm unclear about the '$query->set' first part of my question - does that also need to be changed in similar manner?